# Where can I host freely many images with a constant url?

Tags: image, hosting, web-hosting

I am looking for a hosting service to host several images. This hosting service must satisfy the following 2 criteria:

1) Be free

2) Constant prefix URL, e.g.:

```
https://www.hostfiles.com/img/img1.png
https://www.hostfiles.com/img/img2.png
https://www.hostfiles.com/img/img3.png
...
```

Not indispensable but preferably:

3) Upload capacity: +1GB/month

4) Transfer capacity: +8GB/month

I have been using Google's Firebase (which meets these criteria) but would like to test other alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some Alternatives to Firebase (as of June 2018):

**Amazon Web Services**: https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/

AWS offers a free tier with 5GB file storage, and 50GB data transfer. This is the solution which will likely suit you the best.

*More details: https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/pricing/*

Other Solutions:

**Backendless**: https://backendless.com

Solution offers 1GB file storage, and 60 API calls per minute. The exact amount of data transfer is not specified.

**Google Drive**: https://drive.google.com

Solution offer s 15GB file storage, and data transfer limit is not specified but the threshold should be rather large. Note: Google Drive is not a solution which can be used for static website hosting. Publishing images on the other hand seems doable.

Tutorial: https://www.labnol.org/internet/host-website-on-google-drive/28178/

**Kinvey**: https://www.progress.com/kinvey/

Solution does not specify the limits in the free tier.

**Byet Host**: https://byet.host

I have read that you can have 1GB file storage, 50GB data transfer, however I am unable to verify this.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple services, for example, StackOverflow is using [imgur.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90342), depends on your use it may be [free or not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213547), to know more about the limits check: https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000083326-What-files-can-I-upload-What-is-the-size-limit-

On top of the service that you chose or either if you go with your own homemade solution you could always benefit from a CDN, for example, Cloudflare and its [Mirage Image Optimization](https://www.cloudflare.com/website-optimization/mirage/)